# How to edit multiple fields in single column material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable) for a project. There I have a scenario I need to render and edit multiple fields in a single column conditionally.

This is the scenario

```
{
  title: intl.formatMessage({ ...commonMessages.rate }),
  field: 'fixed',
  render: rowData => {
    if (rowData.config === 'A') {
      if (rowData.type !== 'B') {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Typography variant="body1">
                Pips : {rowData.pips}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1">
                Percentage : {rowData.percentage}
              </Typography>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
      return (
        <Typography variant="body1">
            {rowData.percentage}
        </Typography>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Typography variant="body1">{rowData.fixed}</Typography>
    );
  },
  editComponent: props => {
    if (props.rowData.type === 'A') {
      if (props.rowData.type !== 'B') {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
              <TextField
                id="pips"
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                value={props.rowData.pips}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
              <TextField
                id="percentage"
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                value={props.rowData.percentage}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
      return (
        <TextField
            id="fixed"
            onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
            value={props.rowData.fixed}
        />
      );
    }
```

Here the render and edit components display properly. But since the field is `'fixed'` the values for pips and percentage are not changing since the onChange applies to `fixed` even though any other one in a column changed.

How can I get this fixed ? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `onRowDataChange` prop for that like this:

```
<TextField
   id="pips"
   onChange={e =>
      props.onRowDataChange({
         ...props.rowData,
          pips: e.target.value
         })
       }
       value={props.rowData.pips}
  />
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-77eb5).